# Why am I getting a timeout in the chat app?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on a chat application where I am using FCM, PHP back-end, and Volley for requests.

Initially, when I log in to my application, chat works fine, and fast, but after sometime volley timeout error start coming up and as I am not using any retry policy, chat message gets lost.

And if I increase socket time out and use retry policy then app gets hung.

Here is my code snippet where I am calling API:

```
public void doNetworkRequest(int type, String url, final HashMap<String, String> params, Response.Listener requestListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        StringRequest mRequest = new StringRequest(type, url, requestListener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }
        };
//        int socketTimeout = 500000;
//        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
//        mRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        mQueue.add(mRequest);
    }
```

**This issue is coming almost every API sometimes like login, logout, chatting etc.**

Comment: what version of Volley are you using?

Comment: @Andy: volley version : 1.0.0

Comment: The same issue is present when i use volley 1.1.1(latest one)

Comment: @Sangeeta i think ur server is not responding. so you are getting time out error ..

Comment: did you try it with "postman" or other? is it doing fine with that?are you sure it's not from server side?

Comment: What `POSTMAN PREVIEW` Says ?

Comment: @Asthme but when I am hitting API from postman it takes around 746ms only, but in the app, the timeout error is coming.

Comment: @Man yes i have tried postman, API response is coming in around 746ms

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please check above comments.

Comment: Can you call the api from another medium?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
```

this is for Retrying failed requests and customizing request Timeout

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the API calls are done frequently and gets squeezed. Please check the network transaction in Android Monitoring tab if you are using Android Studio for development. you will get an idea how much network queries are sent on same time.

**As a solution :**
you can do a pipeline for sending requests. Storing a HashMap value for chat messages and status bit. each request starts when the previous message is synced. In such cases you don't need a timer or retry policy (unless the network fails frequently even for single request)

Comment: I am using Volley, where all requests are executing sequentially

Answer (score -1):

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 
DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Increase your `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS`.